# Declare and assign in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new with Angular and TypeScript and I can't figure it out why I can't use my variable after I declare it here.

Something like this.

```
export class aComponent implements OnInit {

  num : Number;
  num = currentUser.Id
```

I got a "Duplicate identifier 'num'" as the error.

This is in a TS file of a component.

Comment: I suggest you read this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the row: "num = currentUser.Id"
and add "**this**.num = currentUser.Id" in the ngOnInit method

Answer (score 1):

It thinks you are trying to declare another variable with same name. (Because you are outside the scope of a method)  If you are trying to initialize num you can do it like this.

```
num: number = currentUser.Id;
```

or if you are declaring currentUser in the class

```
num: number = this.currentUser.Id;
```